# How to interact Mobicents SIP Load Balancer and Mobicents Sip Servlets nodes?

Tags: servlets, sip, jain-sip

The Mobicents SIP Load Balancer selects nodes to serve the SIP requests through a round-robin algorithm for load-balancing picking up nodes from a list of Mobicents Sip Servlets nodes that is created at runtime. The different nodes are responsible for contacting the load balancer and sending to it heartbeats and health status.
My servlet in application uses 5180 port on itself to contact the load balancer. 5065 port is used for connection on slb and it is configured in lb-configuration.properties as internalPort. For example, when an invite sip message is received by slb, it is sent to 5180 port (port is used by sip servlet) from 5060 port (port is used by slb) by using same IP. I do not know where 5180 is defined in system. There is not any definition in server.xml. Could you please help me if you know which configuration file is used for it? Thank you, Hatke

Answer (score 1):

Which version of SIP Servlets do you use ? Tomcat or JBoss ?
If your SIP Servlet application uses 5180 as port this is because you defined it in the server.xml

See https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/Mobicents-SipServlets-Release/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/documentation/html_single/index.html#bsssc-binary-SIP_Servlets_Server-Configuring on configuring the SIP Connectors in the container